# What, if anything, is Eld Vintic Poetry based on?

Tags: inspiration, the-kingkiller-chronicle, poetry

In the Kingkiller books, Kvothe's friend Simmon studies [Eld Vintic](https://kingkiller.fandom.com/wiki/Eld_Vintic) poetry.

[Here's an excerpt](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7343837-i-never-cared-for-poetry-i-said-your-loss-sim):

> Sought we the Scrivani word-work of Surthur
> Long-lost in ledger all hope forgotten
> Yet fast-found for friendship fair the book-bringer
> Hot comes the huntress Fela, flushed with finding
> Breathless her breast her high blood rising
> To ripen the red-cheek rouge-bloom of beauty.

I've only listened to the books, but the poetry had a real rhythm to it that seemed entrancing.

Is it obviously based on any real word poetry, or has Rothfuss stated what if anything it's based on?

Comment: In a Q&A on reddit PR responded to a question "If a fan wanted to try their hand at writing some Eld Vintic poetry, are there set rules to this form?" with "Read some of the old Norse Eddas"

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez thats good info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks a lot like Old English poetry, the most famous example of which is [Beowulf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beowulf#Form_and_metre); the meter and alliteration and wording all seem similar. See also [Alliterative verse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliterative_verse). Here is a short snippet of a [translation of Beowulf](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/50114/beowulf-modern-english-translation):

```
LO, praise of the prowess of people-kings
of spear-armed Danes, in days long sped,
we have heard, and what honor the athelings won!
Oft Scyld the Scefing from squadroned foes,
from many a tribe, the mead-bench tore,
awing the earls. Since erst he lay
friendless, a foundling, fate repaid him:
for he waxed under welkin, in wealth he throve,
till before him the folk, both far and near,
who house by the whale-path, heard his mandate,
gave him gifts: a good king he!
```

A commenter points out this Q&A with the author, Patrick Rothfuss, [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tabled/comments/1vd0jc/table_im_fantasy_author_patrick_rothfuss_ama/):

> [Q:] If a fan wanted to try their hand at writing some Eld Vintic poetry, are there set rules to this form?

> [A, from Rothfuss:] Read some of the old Norse Eddas...

(Both Beowulf and the Eddas fall under the category of "alliterative verse"; see the wikipedia link above).

Comment: I have come across that before but I would never have made the connection. In particular the Kenning seem to match, but one of the devices I'm yet to place is 'voice' its in (e.g. how the poem uses "Sought we ..." not "We sought ..." or "Hot comes the huntress Fela" vs. "Fela the huntress comes, hot, ...").

Comment: Is "sought we" vs "we sought" a difference in voice, or just in word order? "Sought we" puts the accent on the first syllable of the line, which fits better with this form. (Your second example fits this pattern as well.) I can't decide whether phrases like "word-work" or "the book-bringer" count as kennings or not (they're not as metaphorical/abstract as classic examples like "the whale-road")

Comment: Word order irregularities as a poetic device is hyperbaton (at least that's what Google tells me). I'd say they seem enough like kenning to count ... But I'm not expert

Comment: I agree with the comparison to the Poetic Edda. When I first read it, all I could think of was the songs of the Rohirrim in LOTR, which are heavily based on the Norse cultures and language.